# List object to replace nan values in pandas cells problem

Tags: python, pandas, list, replace

I would try to put various list objects to pandas dataframe cells within a for loop. I use *.at* method, the problem is after about 200th iteration the *.at* method does not give back an "nan" value to replace, but an array of "nan" values, so i cannot put a single new value into it. What is the preblem?

```
x = ['string1', 'string2','string3']
data['Var1'] = pd.Series()
data['Var1'] = data['Var1'].astype('object')

for i in range(0,len(data)):

    data.at[data.index[i], 'Var1'] = x


ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 131072
```

Br, Roland

Comment: the MRE does not work, data has no len.

Comment: Sorry. i did not mentioned that "data" is alredy an existing dataframe with more then 100.000 rows. I just made a new column which I want to fill up with values